# How to display different names in "git log" when committing with different users

Tags: git

Let me start off by saying I'm a huge Git (and Ubuntu) noob. I will try and explain my problem as clear as possible, but I find this hard, because I'm not really sure of what I'm doing or if I'm using the right approach.

**Here's the situation:**

I have a remote Ubuntu server with a bare repo (/opt/git/repo.git). I have two users on my server: `bram` and `test`, both are in the group `git`. `Git` has write access to the directory. Both users have a different name and email configured with `git config --global`. The contents of /home/bram/.gitconfig:

```
[user]
        name = Bram Van der Sype
        email = ...
[core]
        editor = vim
```

Contents of /home/test/.gitconfig

```
[user]
       name = Test test
       email = ...
```

On my local machine (Windows 7) I have 2 clones of the repo: one actual development repo, that was checked out with `bram` and a second clone (for testing purposes only, in a different directory) that was checked out with `test`.

**What did I do:**

Changed some lines in a file in the second, test clone. I then committed these lines locally and pushed them to the origin (using SSH, I am asked for the `test` password). I switched to the actual development directory, did a `git pull origin master` and opened the changed file. I see the changed lines done in the testing dir. I then do a `git log -2` and `git blame index.php`, hoping to see the user.name associated with `test` linked to the commit and the changes.

*However*, the only name I see, is the `bram` one.

**What do I want?**

To be able to see who did the actual commit. Is this something I can do with gitosis (something I saw mentioned when googling)? Did I configure something wrong? Will I need to commit from another machine/Windows user account? Any help, instructions or references to documentation are more than welcome!

Comment: How does the user `bram` on your remote Ubuntu server relate to any user called `bram` on your local Windows machine ? ditto for `test`

Comment: I'm assuming the local user on the windows computer is unimportant, as the SSH user is doing the push. But if I understand what you're saying, I have to configure the usernames locally?

Comment: can you run `git config --get user.name` on your Windows machine ?

Comment: yes, it's the gitconfig on your Windows machine that matters for committing, not the gitconfig on the remote repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you commit your changes you need to be logged in as that particular user. It doesn't matter who cloned the repo. I suspect you were logged in as bram when making changes to the test repo.

Comment: I checked the repo out as the test user, when pushing, it also asked me to log in as the test user, so I presume I was remotely logged in as the test user? No?

When I do "git push origin master" in the test dir, it says "test@example.com's password".

Comment: what you really did was to connect as the test user using `SSH`, and pulled and pushed the repo. What you do when you commit has nothing to do with that user or any user on the remote server.

Comment: Also thanks to Thong Kuah for helping me find the solution, that's what I needed to do!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that in both repos there are different settings, I mean in

`$TEST_REPO/.git/config`  and `$BRAM_REPO/.git/config`

```
[user]
        name = Name
        email = email@address.com
```

??

Comment: Yes (I will also add this information in the question):
Contents of /home/bram/.gitconfig
    [user]
            name = Bram Van der Sype
            email = bram.vandersype@gmail.com
    [core]
            editor = vim

  
Contents of /home/test/.gitconfig
    [user]
           name = Test test
           email = test@bramvandersype.be